# How can I tell which of my Google Apps Script projects I have deployed as libraries?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have many dozen small GAS scripts bound to Google Sheets, and a few fairly large projects that are both bound and deployed as libraries. Is there some way I can see which projects have been deployed as libaries when I open the dashboard? I apologize if I've overlooked some conspicuous control or menu choice.

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more clarity about the terminology you're using? When you mention '**projects**' and '**scripts**' in the context of Google Sheets, are you referring to individual `.gs` script files that are linked to the Google Sheet, or are you talking about the entire *Apps Script projects* that can be bound to a Google Sheet? This will help the community better understand your question about identifying deployed libraries on the dashboard.